# I am calculating LST for Mumbai

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, spatial-analysis, land-surface-temperature, research

I am calculating LST for Mumbai and I found that only Airport and Slum, Barrel land is having high LST than any other region. I need to analyze it more if its just showing all area cooler in city like Mumbai except slum?[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am looking for the research where I can understand that UHI of Mumbai is high due to urbanization and not only slum also other regions are affected by LST so this result is fine or I need to do some more analysis , can you please suggest?